# Threading issue, simultaneous thread limit, maximum threads running at the same time issue

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to run a console process against each country. All the countries are in a datatable. Since the process for each country took 3-4 days. I have decided to run 4 countries at the same time to consume all 4 four processor of my quad core machine.

I write the above code, but the problem with this code is, it runs all the thread at the same time. I want a maximum of 4 thread simultaneously and the rest wait for their turn. I don't mind if the application stuck in country loop and wait for the threads to be finished and start next thread immediately.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Countries");

    #region DataProcessing
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn();
    dc1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc1.ColumnName = "CountryID";

    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
    dc2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc2.ColumnName = "CountryName";

    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["CountryID"] = 1;
    dr["CountryName"] = "US";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //similar code...

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["CountryID"] = 20;
    dr["CountryName"] = "KR";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    #endregion

    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 5);

    foreach (DataRow drLoop in dt.Rows) 
    {
        Thread job = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadJob), 5);
        job.Start(drLoop["CountryName"].ToString());
    }
}
static void ThreadJob(Object country) 
{
    //Do Something
    MessageBox.Show(country.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Which version of C# do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the ThreadPool- you are just starting up a Thread for each country:

```
foreach (DataRow drLoop in dt.Rows) 
{
    Thread job = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadJob), 5);
    job.Start(drLoop["CountryName"].ToString());
}
```

Try this instead:

```
foreach (DataRow drLoop in dt.Rows) 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadJob), drLoop["CountryName"].ToString());
```

Comment: Great Chris, you are the man, really champ. I was stuck with this issue since last 2-3 days, you did this man, you did this.

Answer (score 2):

You do not use *ThreadPool* as for each data row you create a new *Thread*. And limit threads in the pool is generally a [bad idea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx).

> Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread
>   pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse
>   effect on code libraries you use.
>
> Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems.
>   If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching
>   overhead becomes a significant factor.

You can use `Parallel` and `Task` classes to limit the number of threads.